# Expected number of rolls before rolling a 6 given that the first two rolls are not a 6

Tags: probability-theory

You roll a 6-sided repeatedly until you see a 6. Let X= the number of rolls until you see a 6. Let A be the event that you do **not** see a 6 on the first two rolls. What is $E[X|A]$?

I know that $E[X|A] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot Pr(X=k|A)$. I also think that $Pr(A)=\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$ since you can roll anything other than a 6 on the first two rolls.

I'm just struggling a little because technically shouldn't $Pr(X=1|A)$ and $Pr(X=2|A)$ be both 0? Since you can't a roll a 6 on the first or second rolls and also *not* roll a 6 on the first two rolls at the same time.

For $Pr(X=3|A)$ I figured that it's calculated like this:$$Pr(X=3|A) = \frac{Pr(X=3 \cap A)} {Pr(A)}=\frac{\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}} {\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{6}$$

I've deduced that this means that: $$Pr(X=k|A)=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}, k\ge3$$

But I'm not sure if this is correct. I'm also not quite sure how to calculate the sum if this is the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression for $P(X=k|A)$ where $k\geq 3$ is correct. As you noticed,
$P(X=1|A)=P(X=2|A)=0$, thus
$$E[X|A] = \sum_{k=3}^\infty k \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-3}\frac{1}{6}.$$

You can short-circuit the computation of this sum by noting that conditional on $A$, the variable $X$ has the same distribution as $2+Y$, where $Y$ has Geometric distribution with parameter $\frac 16$.

Thus $E[X|A] = 2 + E[Y] = 2+6=8.$